# How to select line that match from ansible facts?

Tags: ansible

There is ansible task with ansible_facts manipulations:

```
- name: "Output facts"
  debug: 
    msg:
     CPU_TYPE: "{{ansible_processor|select('match', '.*CPU.*')|list|unique}}"
  register: custom_result
```

How I can select lines contains CPU from this array:

```
    "CPU_TYPE": [
        "0",
        "GenuineIntel",
        "Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8550U CPU @ 1.80GHz",
        "1",
        "GenuineIntel",
        "Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8550U CPU @ 1.80GHz",
        "2",
        "GenuineIntel",
        "Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8550U CPU @ 1.80GHz",
        "3",
        "GenuineIntel",
        "Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8550U CPU @ 1.80GHz",
        "4",
        "GenuineIntel",
        "Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8550U CPU @ 1.80GHz",
        "5",
        "GenuineIntel",
        "Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8550U CPU @ 1.80GHz",
        "6",
        "GenuineIntel",
        "Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8550U CPU @ 1.80GHz",
        "7",
        "GenuineIntel",
        "Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8550U CPU @ 1.80GHz"
    ],
```

Currently I get the error:

```
"CPU_TYPE": "<generator object select_or_reject at 0x7facb2065930>",
```

Regards

**UPD:**

```
How to get value from squre brackets:
- name: "Output facts"
  debug: 
    msg:
     CPU_TYPE: "{{ansible_processor|select('match', '.*CPU.*')|list|unique}}"
  register: custom_result
```

From this:

```
    "CPU_TYPE": [
        "Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8550U CPU @ 1.80GHz"
        ],
```

To this:

```
    "CPU_TYPE": "Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8550U CPU @ 1.80GHz"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Q: *"I get the error:"*
>
> `"CPU_TYPE": "<generator object select_or_reject at 0x7facb2065930>"`

A: Create a list from the selected items

```
CPU_TYPE: "{{ ansible_processor|select('match', '.*CPU.*')|list }}"
```

---

For example, print 1st element of the list

```
- set_fact:
    CPU_TYPE: "{{ ansible_processor|select('match', '.*CPU.*')|list }}"
- debug:
    msg: "{{ CPU_TYPE[0] }}"
```

Use filters *`unique`* to keep unique items in the list only. Use filter *`first`* to select the first item of the list. For example

```
- set_fact:
    CPU_TYPE_FIRST: "{{ ansible_processor|
                        select('match', '.*CPU.*')|
                        list|
                        unique|
                        first }}"
```

Comment: thanks, can you please answer how to get  value from brackets  like this: "CPU_TYPE":  "Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8550U CPU @ 1.80GHz"

Comment: Thanks, no way to do this via filter?

Comment: The ``first`` filter is able to select 1st item. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks but is it clever to do this way: `{{ansible_processor|select('match', '.*CPU.*')|list|unique|json_query('[0]') }}` ?

Comment: In your case all items in the list are equal. The result will be a list with one item only. There is no difference in ``first`` and ``json_query('[0]')``. ``json_query`` is a strong tool worth to review.